# C# работа с базой данных

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms

Как работают с базой данных в C# у WinForm?
Пишут руками запросы или другими методами? Читал о паттерне репозиторий, где все действия с базой происходят через него. Или может использую что-то другое? 
Я написал классы для select, update, delete, которые возвращают строку или Command. После чего я их отправляю в метод ExecuteNonQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возможности через ORM такие (подразумевается, что работаете с SQL-базой):

- [ADO.NET Entity Framework](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework),
- NHibernate,
- другие реализации [ORM для .NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software#.NET).

Напрямую с SQL Server через семейство классов в пространстве имен System.Data.SqlClient.

А вообще весьма удобно работать через [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb386976.aspx).